# How to add a word to the Mail "dictionary"

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, sonoma

How to add a word to the mail app dictionary (ie. thinks it is misspelled but it is not).  I have read that there should be a "Learn Spelling" option in the contextual menu.  I can't find "Learn Spelling" in Sonoma.  Seems basic but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Open Finder > go to folder

Open /Users/**YOU**/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary

Open it and modify

Comment: Thank you for that help.  Since I have Sonoma 14.3.1 what I did was in Finder, Alt click Go to get to Library, then Users/ME/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary  and then entered the new word in the text box.

Comment: @HaleKell happy it worked for you